# Recommended Go build system for a CI server?

Tags: go

So I have a go project with go-gettable dependencies, tests, etc.

I want to integrate it into Jenkins. Is there an automated build system for go that anyone recommends for this use case, other than writing makefiles?

I need:

1. <s>automatic installation of go-get deps (they can be in a spec file of course)</s>
2. recursive build.
3. running tests.
4. GOPATH/GOROOT management (to isolate SDKs and paths)

I've used godag in the past for this sort of job but it seems a bit unmaintained.

EDIT: For the time being I'm living with the following script entered directly into Jenkins as a build step:

```
#this gets the dependencies but doesn't install them, avoiding permission problems
go get -d

#build the packages, -x outputs the compiler command line
go build -x

#this was tricky - ./... means "for each sub-package recursively"
go test ./...
```

Comment: Go get fetches your dependencies by default. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: go test doesn't seem to work recursively though. or am I missing something?

Comment: another problem with go-gettting automatically - my own app has a namespace that's not go-gettable (e.g. - example.com/myproject). that's fine usually, only go get tries to get it automatically and fails, and there apparently is no way of telling it not to do that.

Comment: I dont know about recursive tests, and regarding the local packages, they should be fine if the package is located in the project directory in `gopath` as in `src -> [project] -> [local package]`. The tool would look for the local package in src by default and you only need to specify the local package in the following way: `[project directory] / [package directory]`

Comment: @YasirG. read my edit above, it turned out fine including recursive testing, without further tools. thanks!

Comment: nice, good to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with teamcity as well.

Here is an example for building terraform.

Teamcity agent setup:

- Install Go
- Add Go to path
- Don't forget to restart agent as path was changed

Teamcity build setup:

- Use agent side checkout (if we want to include the .git folder, which a lot of build scripts make use of)
- Use checkout rule (we want to use the Go convention):

  +:. => src/github.com/mitchellh/terraform

Build steps:

```
echo cd %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%
cd "%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%"
path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;%env.Path%;%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\bin;
echo path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;%env.Path%;%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\bin;
set GOPATH=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%
echo set GOPATH=%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%

echo "Getting dependancies"
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/vet
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer
go get github.com/mitchellh/gox

echo cd %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\src\github.com\mitchellh\terraform
cd "%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\src\github.com\mitchellh\terraform"

echo "Update resources"
go get ./...

echo "Run static code analysis"
go tool vet -asmdecl -atomic -bool -buildtags -copylocks -methods -nilfunc -printf -rangeloops -shift -structtags -unsafeptr .

echo "Build"
cd scripts
sh build.sh

echo "Run unit tests"
go test -timeout=30s -parallel=4

echo "Run code coverage"
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
rm coverage.out
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you send coverage data to TeamCity?

Comment: With TeamCity, it is also possible to build Go apps without extra installation at the Agent side. You can specify that the build step should run in the appropriate Docker container (for instance, golang:1.9-alpine), run the tests and cross-compile the binaries. To get the coverage data it would be enough to specify artefacts/files that should be published in the general settings of the build configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a Team City build server on a Mac that runs a rake file, in the rake file I do all the commands to get dependancies, (go gets), tests and builds to the correct environment.

let me know if you want any pointers in writing the Rake files,

As a side note, i have been creating functional tests for REST Api's using this frame work. This has saved my code many times over. http://github.com/DigitalInnovation/cucumber_rest_api

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for some tool that will at least generate a makefile from or configuration options from my source tree. I mean I can just write a bash script, but I was hoping for something more automated.

Answer (score 0):

Since August 2019, TeamCity 2019.1 now supports Go directly.
See "[Building Go programs in TeamCity](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2019/08/building-go-programs-in-teamcity/)"

> To enable Go support in TeamCity,
>
> - go to `Build Configuration Settings` | `Build Features`,
>
>   - click `Add build feature`, and
>   - select `Golang` from the list.

[image: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/teamcity/files/2019/08/golang-build-feature.png]

> Support for Go is provided by TeamCity out of the box, there are no external plugins required.
>   TeamCity parses results of go test command execution. The results are persisted and it is possible to review the figures in a historical perspective.
>   Consequently, all the TeamCity features that are related to test reporting are now available for Go developers.